# How to speed up throughput of "$find . -type f -printf '%f\n' -exec cat {} \; >MY_OUTPUT_FILE"

Tags: linux, performance

I have over 500K very small files in a folder(each file contains a few words). i want to merge all their file names and their contents into a single file. This command runs very slowly. kindly help to alter this command or provide a faster alternate command. thanks in advance.

```
$find . -type f -printf '%f\n' -exec cat {} \; >MY_OUTPUT_FILE
```

Comment: are the files in deep-level folders?

Answer (score 1):

Use grep:

```
grep . * > ../output
```